# How to get only the top row from a groupby on DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a DataFrame that has multiple closing prices for a stock at several intervals in a day. I am trying to do a groupby to get the final closing price (the first row when I apply the max function on the Date column).

My code for the groupby look like this:

```
closingPrice = Data.groupby([Data['Date'].dt.date, 'Close'])["Date"].max()
```

This results in the following output:

```
Date        Close  
2019-11-11  1706.75   2019-11-11 14:15:00
            1710.75   2019-11-11 10:15:00
            1711.00   2019-11-11 12:15:00
            1712.00   2019-11-11 11:15:00
            1712.85   2019-11-11 13:15:00
                              ...        
2020-11-06  3238.75   2020-11-06 14:15:00
            3240.00   2020-11-06 12:15:00
            3243.65   2020-11-06 13:15:00
```

How do I change the above line so that I get just the first row? I need only one row per day.

I am new to pandas and I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if I understand your data correctly, you don't want to put `Close` in the groupby. Each transaction has a time stamp `Date` and `Close` value.

You can use `idxmax()` to get the index, and loc:

```
Data.loc[Data.groupby([Data['Date'].dt.date])["Date"].idxmax()]
```

If you only care for the `Close` price, you can pass the column to `loc`:

```
Data.loc[Data.groupby([Data['Date'].dt.date])["Date"].idxmax(), 'Close']
```

Comment: Thank you, Quang Hoang. The idxmax() function worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working with exchange prices in Pandas.

I have created a file (excel, csv, etc) which stores all relevant trading days, so normal week days without holidays.
Afterwards I Import these „calendar“ and merge the exchange prices to these dates.

You can probably do the same with your day and time timestamps, if days and end times are predictable.
Another advantage of this way is, you can check for missing prices, as you know what data should be there.

I can share my code tomorrow, if you are interested

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Nils. The only problem is that this data is automatically received via a stream and I have to do this on the fly. It would be interesting to look at your code. Do share it if you are okay.

Comment: This is not an answer, better fit for a comment. Please consider editing it with related information.